# @autowired annotation for service class is not working in @configure class spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

> when i am using @autowire to inject my dependencies   in Configuration
>   class its giving me as null please refer the code below .

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {



    @Autowired
    AppService   appService;

    @Bean
    public BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor beanPostProcessor() {
        return new BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor() {

            public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory arg0) throws BeansException {

            }

            public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanRegistry) throws BeansException {

                createBeans(beanRegistry);

            }

        };
    }

    private void createBeans(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanRegistry,DataSourceConfigService ds) {


        appService.getDbDetails();
```

> appService is null  here if i will call it using this way 
>   BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor beanPostProcessor(AppService
>   appService) then  in AppServiceImpl  class  AppDao  dependency will be null

```
}
}


//// Service

@Service
public class AppServiceImpl  implements AppService{


    @Autowired
    AppDao ds;


    @Override
    public List<A> getDatabaseConfiguration() {
        return ds.getDbDetails(); // here ds is null 
    }


}

//dao
@Repository
public class AppDaoImpl implements AppDao {

    @Qualifier("nameParamJdbcTemplate")
    @Autowired
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate nameParamJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<A> getDbDetails() {
        return nameParamJdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_QUERY, new DataSourceMapper());  // nameParamJdbcTemplate is null 
    }


// datasource config

@Configuration
public class DataSourceBuilderConfig {

 @Bean(name = "dbSource")
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
 @Primary
 public DataSource dataSource1() {

    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

 }

 @Bean(name = "nameParamJdbcTemplate")
 @DependsOn("dbSource")
 @Autowired
 public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1(@Qualifier("dbSource") DataSource dbSource) {
       return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dbSource);
 }




}
```

> What i want is when ever my beanPostProcessor() 
>       is executed i want all my dependent beans should be instantiated ie

```
 @Autowired
  AppService appService;  

@Autowired
AppDao ds;    
@Qualifier("nameParamJdbcTemplate")
@Autowired
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate nameParamJdbcTemplate; 

I am new to spring so any help or working examples would be great. Thanks
```

Comment: You should also always consider using Constructor injection over Field Injection, http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Answer (score 1):

It is `null` because this `@Configuration` class also defines a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` that forces the context to create that bean very early on.

Because you are using field injection, the context has to resolve `AppService` bean but it can't yet because the post-processor have to be applied first.

Your configuration looks very complex so you may want to simplify it a bit:

- Separate low-level infrastructure configuration from main configuration
- Always define such post processor as `public static` method so that the context can invoke the `@Bean` method without having to construct the class first.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneNicoll My main requirement is when **BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor** is called i need to call one service call as mentioned in the code is there a way we can injection bean forcefully

Comment: You can't do that. A `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` as its name indicates, handles the bean definition registry. This is invoked way before any bean gets actually created.